# Integrate Amadeus v2 Hotel API instead of v3 Hotel AP?

Tags: amadeus

I'm developing a hotel booking website, and I have observed that Amadeus v2 hotel API returns more information compared to Amadeus v3. Is there a method to still use the v2 Hotel API? If not, I have some following questions related to the v3 Hotel API:

1. How can we retrieve Hotel and Room amenities?
2. How can we obtain hotel contact information?
3. Is it possible to cancel a booking?
4. And most importantly, does Amadeus v3 Hotel API support children for hotel search?

I'm try to deploy Amadeus v2 Hotel API but got an error

`{ "errors": [ { "code": 38196, "title": "Resource not found", "detail": "The targeted resource doesn't exist", "status": 404 } ] }`

Answer (score 0):

The Hotel Search v2 API is decommissioned and replaced by the [Hotel Search v3](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/hotels/api-doc/hotel-search) API.

You can check the [migration guide here](https://amadeus4dev.github.io/developer-guides/migration-guides/hotel-search/), about how you can migrate your application to the latest version.

For booking cancellations, you will have to do this offline by contacting the providers. Also, the contact information and amenities are excluded from the response. However, you can find some workarounds provided [here](https://amadeus4dev.github.io/developer-guides/migration-guides/hotel-search/#faq).

Children guests are not supported for the API and the booking should be managed the same way as for adults.